# Cherry-pick not mark merge

Tags: git, bitbucket

First, sorry, English isn't my native language.

A question:

- I have 2 branches in my local and remote repository.

  - 1 = master
  - 2 = branchTest

I did a commit in branchTest, and then I did a push to my remote repository at Bitbucket. In Bitbucket, it shows 1 commit ahead of branchTest, it's correct, because I didn't merge with master.

Then, I execute:

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick commitNumber
git push origin master
```

This command makes merge between just single commit (commitNumber).

**The problem: Bitbucket still show that exists 1 commit ahead of branchTest.**

**Question: Only merge mark that a commmits was merged?**

When I execute git merge branchTest, bitbucket show merged done.

Comment: `git co` is not a native git command, it looks like you're using an alias for `git checkout`, is that correct?

Comment: Yes Cupcake, co is my alias for checkout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cherry-pick creates another commit, with anoter commitNumber
so yes, only merge "mark that commit as merged"

Comment: Hi, Ruslan Ostafiychuk,

I understood your explanation.

Exists another command that execute single merge and mark a merged (that commit)?
I don't want makes a merged of all changes in branch, then I use cherry-pick.
This is negative point of your use, but have this problem (not marked merge).

Thanks.